# Why is $\frac{1}{3}=0.2\overline{31}$ in 5-adic expansion?

Tags: p-adic-number-theory

> Why is $\frac{1}{3}=0.2\overline{31}$ in 5-adic expansion ?

I get:

$\frac{1}{3}=\frac15+3\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac15\right)^{2k}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac15\right)^{2k+1}=0.13131313\dots=0.\overline{13}$

Something msut be wrong ?

Comment: That's the base $5$ expansion, which is different from the $5$-adic expansion.

Comment: In $5$-adic numbers, you have $$\frac13 = 2+3\cdot 5 + 1\cdot 5^2 + 3\cdot 5^3 + 1 \cdot 5^4 +\cdots $$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Thanks, how is the notation in the p-adic expansion, I saw different sources but they didn't help

Comment: Ah, well, that is not what this author means, because the given expression is the $5$-adic expansion in terms of "$p$-adic numbers." Well, it's decimal point is in the wrong place... @Jean-ClaudeArbaut (By author, I mean whoover informed the OP that 1/3 had that $p$-adic expression.)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If you write any number $\alpha=\sum a_ip^i$, is then $a_i\in[0,\dots,p-1]$ or $a_i\in Z\big/p^iZ$ ?

Comment: $a_i\in\{0,1,\dots,p-1\}$. @inequal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written is the base $5$ representation of the real number $\frac{1}{3}$.

The value $\frac{1}{3}$ in $5$-adic numbers is not just a different representation, but in some sense, a different number.

The standard $5$-adic representation of $\frac{1}{3}$ is actually $$\frac{1}{3}=2.\overline{31}.$$

Note the different placement of the decimal point from the expression in your question. $0.2\overline{31}$ is actually $\frac{5}{3}$ in $5$-adic numbers.

Comment: Here is the source: http://cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/docs/r09.pdf at the bottom of the $1$st page

Comment: Yeah, that's either very non-standard notation, or merely wrong, depending on how you read things. The author is clearly talking about the same series, but the standard notation is to put the decimal point after the $2$.

Comment: The author's notation isn't horrible. In particular, using this notation, $n/p^k$ can be written by writing the standard (real) base $p$ exapansion of the expression and merely reversing the string. But the standard notation puts the $p^0$ term before the decimal.

Comment: Whoops, you are correct. Fixed. @inequal

Comment: I like running the $p$-adic digits to the left: $...1313132;\,$. In this way, you can do hand computations *exactly* as you did in elementary school, using $p$-ary addition and multiplication tables as aid. Of course that applies to $+,-,\times$ only. Division has to be tabulated differently, but it’s easy enough to figure out.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{1}{3}$ is in base $5$ 
$$\frac{1}{3}= 0.131313\ldots_{(5)}= 0.\overline{13}_{(5)}$$
since
$$0.131313\ldots_{(5)}= \frac{0.131313\ldots_{(5)}}{0.444444\ldots_{(5)}}= \frac{13_{(5)}}{44_{(5)}}= \frac{1}{3}$$

Therefore, $-\frac{1}{3}$ in $5$-adic is
$$-\frac{1}{3}= \ldots 131313. $$

(use $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} x^n= 0$ )
so now substract ( that's why @Lubin: 's point of view is so useful) $-\frac{1}{3}$ from $0.$ and get in $5$-adics
$$\frac{1}{3} = \ldots1313132.= \overline{13}2.
$$